# Slider PHP loop

Tags: php

I am working on a image slider for a website, the user can add up to 0 - 3 images to the slider. What kind of loop should I use to make this code more efficient and DRY? "data-slide-number" starts from 0 and changes based on the image. The images are not "required" so there won't always be 3 images.

```
<?php 
// image urls
$pr_img_1       = first image url;
$pr_img_2       = second image url;
$pr_img_3       = third image url;
?>

<div class="carousel-inner">
 <?php if($pr_img_1); { ?> 
    <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
        <img src="<?= esc_html( $pr_img_1 ); ?>">
    </div>
 <?php } ?>

 <?php if($pr_img_2); { ?> 
    <div class="active item" data-slide-number="1">
        <img src="<?= esc_html( $pr_img_2 ); ?>">
    </div>
 <?php } ?>

 <?php if($pr_img_3); { ?> 
    <div class="active item" data-slide-number="2">
        <img src="<?= esc_html( $pr_img_3 ); ?>">
    </div>
  <?php } ?>

</div><!-- Carousel nav -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the below code.

```
<?php
$pr_imgs = array("first image url","second image url","third image url");
$i = 0;
foreach($pr_imgs as $pimg)
{
?>
    <div class="active item" data-slide-number="<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <img src="<?= esc_html( $pimg ); ?>">
    </div>
<?php   
$i++;
}
?>
```

Using foreach you don't have to take care of the number of image path.

Comment: yes, perfect answer